# airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: webserver

Tags: python, gunicorn, airflow

I am trying to start my airflow webserver, but it says it is an unrecognised argument

```
$ airflow webserver
[2017-05-25 15:06:44,682] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

[2017-05-25 15:06:45,099] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags
usage: airflow [-h] [-v]
airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: webserver
```

Seeing as most of the other arguments are broken too, I have already tried to reinstall airflow:
`sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall airflow==1.7.1.3`

It was working just fine until I decided to restart it...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as I was writing the last line of the question. I was restarting because I updated a DAG, in which, I had added an `ArgumentParser`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-v', '--verbose',
    help="Print lots of debugging statements",
    action="store_const", dest="loglevel", const=logging.DEBUG,
    default=logging.INFO,
)
```

Apparently that is not allowed in Airflow DAGs