# airflow: error: unrecognized arguments - Airflow scheduler error

Tags: airflow

I created a DAG as follows :

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 12, 30),
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='TEST',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=30),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False)

task_op = DummyOperator(task_id='task', dag=dag)
```

saved it as `my_test.py` and uploaded it to the DAG folder.

Started the DAG manually from the UI the DAG is queued but the task immediately fails. There is no log for the task but the scheduler log shows.

```
usage: airflow [-h]
               {resetdb,render,variables,connections,pause,task_failed_deps,version,trigger_dag,initdb,test,unpause,dag_state,run,list_tasks,backfill,list_dags,kerberos,worker,webserver,flower,scheduler,task_state,pool,serve_logs,clear,upgradedb}
               ...
airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: my_test.py
```

I never encountered this before.  What is the problem?

There is a similar question [airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184710/airflow-error-unrecognized-arguments-webserver)  but it's totally different. The solution there is irrelevant here.

Please advise what is the problem here

Comment: Which Executor is this with? Airflow schedules a command like `airflow run dag_id task_id <execution_date>` and unless you named your dag or a task `my_test.py` that doesn't look like something that should be in the command itself.

Comment: @dlamblin LocalExcecutor. This isn't my first DAG. everything else is working on my machine. For some reason this one fails and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? I think it's thrown by: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/airflow#L31 or L32 which means it's implemented in the core ArgumentParser module. I suppose a try catch around those lines that outputs the current arguments before re-throwing is what you'd find useful.

Comment: @dlamblin There is no trace log. The task never created a log. The only indication from the problem is from the airflow-scheduler.err  and it shows the message I posted. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should `grep -r 'ArgumentParser' path/to/dags_folder` to confirm that it isn't the same issue as the other question and answer you found. Without more context it doesn't seem like this message would be generated in the scheduler's logs by a scheduled dag_run, but rather by the dag parsing loop for the dagbag.

I say this because the DAG you've shared with the added imports below works normally on my 1.10 installation.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

It might also be worth looking at: [AIRFLOW-270](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-270?jql=text%20~%20%22unrecognized%20arguments%22%20and%20project%20%3D%20%22Apache%20Airflow%22%20) where a space in the directory name lead to this kind of exception; I don't think that's what you had happening to you, but it's worth ruling out. Also the report seems to show that in v1.7 the preceding lines to the error would have logged the full command that failed like:

> `Command 'airflow run cleanup_test select_users 2016-08-03T18:20:38.308518 --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/Test DAG/test.py ' returned non-zero exit status 2
>   airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: DAG/test.py
>   [2016-08-03 18:39:54,971: ERROR/MainProcess] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[624cf49c-e765-468e-9227-fd2941ddb779] raised unexpected: AirflowException('Celery command failed',)`

In [AIRFLOW-2119](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2119) it shows that in v1.9 the original command that failed is output below the `airflow: error: unrecognized arguments` line.

Comment: I deleted the DAG. recreated it with new file name and new dag_id and now the same code works. I guess this is a weird Airflow failure

Comment: @Luis glad to hear it's resolved; A bit troubling that we don't know why it happened.

Comment: well the airflow repo is full with bug reports so even if I could reproduce it again I doubt it would have been fixed. However what I can suggest is to fix the error written to the log. Showing `airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: my_test.py` isn't enough.. Showing also the command that airflow actually try to execute could have help to figure this out. Maybe you can pull some strings with the community to apply such fix.

Comment: @Luis it seems from a couple Bug Reports I linked to the answer, the original command that failed should have been logged either below or above what you excerpted. Oh I see, that's only in Celery Executor, not Local Executor. Let me see about whether it can be made common.

Comment: @dlambin were you able to figure why it happens and if it's going to be fixed by Airflow?

Comment: @Luis I don't have a reproducible occurrence of this myself. Also i don't know if this would be a priority for trying to get 2.0 RCed, or whatever is currently on the maintainer's plates.